# Ways to measure a systems hardware requirements

Tags: .net, performance, hardware, analysis

I was wondering if there is a tool to measure the resources needed to run an app? We have developed an app that runs fine on all modern computers, but I am curious about "how low can we go".

The app in question is developed in .NET, so there might be some code analyzer or something, but I am more curious in general if there is a tool you can fire up, let it analyze your running executable and figure out the amount of RAM and maybe CPU power needed.

Answer (score 0):

What about the Task Manager? In the processes pane it shows the CPU and memory used by each process.